# How to find G1 Young and Old Generation metrics in Micrometer?

Tags: prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

The prometheus client used to emit these metrics in my Java application `jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count` that had labels for G1 Young Generation and G1 Old Generation like the following-

```
jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count{gc="G1 Old Generation",} 0.0
jvm_gc_collection_seconds_count{gc="G1 Young Generation",} 0.0
```

However, I'm working on a Spring Boot application that no longer uses Prometheus client but uses Micrometer client instead. The closest metric here I have is `jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count`  but it doesn't have G1 yound/old labels.

Is there a way to get that information in my Spring Boot application that uses Micrometer client?

Comment: did the answer I gave answer your question? If so, I wouldn't mind an accept and upvote. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

With Micrometer releases up until `1.10.x` the garbage collector name isn't part of the metric tag. You can only reason about the used garbage collector based on the `cause`-tag.

```
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",} 6.0
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",} 0.017
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",} 0.004
```

But, this issue was [discussed recently](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/3670) and is part of Micrometer [`1.11.0-M2`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/releases/tag/v1.11.0-M2). (And will likely make it into the final `1.11.0`, I guess. EDIT: It did make it into `1.11.0`.)

```
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",gc="G1 Young Generation",} 6.0
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",gc="G1 Young Generation",} 0.015
jvm_gc_pause_seconds_max{action="end of minor GC",cause="G1 Evacuation Pause",gc="G1 Young Generation",} 0.003
```